# retain order of array using each and image.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I try to use image.onload and having some async issue. The images array will get inconsistent order of array. I checked my db it wans't causing the bug then I realised this async issue with image.onload. Anyone has experience dealing with this?

```
$(data).each(function(i, val) {

  var albumPhoto = '';

  albumPhoto = 'https://example.com/' + this.photo;

  var temp_img = new Image(),

    temp_img.src = albumPhoto;
  temp_img.onload = function() {

    images.push(albumPhoto);

  }
})
```

Comment: Did you try `images[i] = albumPhoto` ?

Comment: You probably meant `albumPhoto = 'https://example.com/' + val.photo;`

Comment: How about `temp_img.load( function() ... );` ?

Comment: @0aslam0 what it does?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `push` to fill your `images` array, but use the index (`i`) that jQuery provides.

i.e.: change `images.push(albumPhoto)` to `images[i] = albumPhoto`

This works because after instantiating an empty array (`images = []`), you can set any index to a value. The other indexes will remain unset.

Here's an example that shows what it would look like (in vanilla js, with a timeout instead of image load)

```js
var target = [],
    source = [1,2,3,4,5];

source.forEach(function(nr, index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    target[index] = nr * 5;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(target));
  }, Math.random() * 500);
});
```

Comment: you are missing big part of my problem, where is the image.onload part?

Comment: The code is an *example* meant to show how the change works without having to recreate all your code. The line "I.e. ... " suggests the actual edit

Answer (score 0):

Put all the images in the array and then remove them when there is an error.

```js
$(data).each(function(i, val) {
  var albumPhoto = 'https://example.com/' + val.photo;
  var temp_img = new Image();
  temp_img.src = albumPhoto;
  images.push(albumPhoto);
  temp_img.onerror = function() {
    var src = this.src;
    var index = images.indexOf(src);
    images.splice(index, 1);

  }
});
```

Comment: there's no error in my case, it's just can't produce consistent order.

Comment: @JennyMok why are you using onload to push images in the array then? You can push it directly without it. It looks like you were only trying to push images that loads and ignore the ones that don't load.